# Hot to edit WooCOmmerce dashboard?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I'm trying to edit the WooCommerce MyAccount dashboard. When you take a look at  my function you can see that I first tried to remove the whole content because I want to set my own one:

```
add_action('woocommerce_account_content', 'test');
function test() {
    return false;
}
```

But this don't works. When I load the account page the default content on the dasboard is still there. I know that I can copy the page to my child theme but this is not possible with my theme so I need to do this with hooks only. Do you have any idea how I can remove the default content so I can add my own div, title and all the stuff in it?

The content I want to change:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can, at best, hide the existing dashboard with CSS and add your own one with hooks.

Comment: But I've successfully added content there but I want to remove the old content too

Comment: Unless you wanna rewrite the my account php file, I believe CSS would be your only option.